After successful appium uiautomator2 driver installment, the driver still not shown on the list of drivers and is considered not installed by server
I'm trying to install the uiautomator2 appium driver on my Windows system. I have 2.5.2 appium and 10.5.2 npm versions. Though the installation process passes without any issues or errors, the system doesn't see the new driver even after reboot.
I use this command:
npm i appium-uiautomator2-driver
The console works without errors and in the end gives me this:
up to date, audited 688 packages in 27s

68 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

I check with appium driver list and get this:
√ Listing available drivers
- uiautomator2 [not installed]
- xcuitest [not installed]
- mac2 [not installed]
- espresso [not installed]
- safari [not installed]
- gecko [not installed]
- chromium [not installed]

Reboot brings the same result.

I am very lost at this point since I don't even get any errors. What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

You should run install with appium instead of npm

appium driver install uiautomator2

